# Is there a way to calculate a median from a subset of rows based on a value from a separate data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, median

I am at a sticking point in some data analysis (been out of the R game for a few years now and jumping back in has been tough).

I have two sets of information and need to pull parts of one data frame based on values in the other.  The one I need to pull information from is a data frame of GPS points with associated times (one GPS point every second).  There are four separate GPS units listed in the file, so for every one time point, there are four locations.

I have a second data frame that has a list of times (over 1,000 time points).  I need to calculate median GPS coordinates for each GPS unit for a one minute window around the times listed in my second data frame.  Is this easily accomplished?

Here are a few rows from the GPS file (the colors refer to the different GPS units):

```r
UNIT    LONG        LAT         TIME    
BLUE    -133.528    57.317723   11:00:00    
ORANGE  -133.546435 57.316681   11:00:00    
PURPLE  -133.54297  57.3112     11:00:00    
YELLOW  -133.53807  57.319616   11:00:00    
BLUE    -133.527995 57.317725   11:00:01    
ORANGE  -133.546425 57.316681   11:00:01    
PURPLE  -133.542961 57.311201   11:00:01    
YELLOW  -133.538061 57.319616   11:00:01    
BLUE    -133.527991 57.317725   11:00:02    
ORANGE  -133.546415 57.316681   11:00:02    
PURPLE  -133.542955 57.311203   11:00:02    
YELLOW  -133.538053 57.319615   11:00:02
```

The other data file is just a list of times

```r
StartTime
11:00:00
11:51:25
12:15:17
```

etc.

I would love to tell you the things I've tried, but I honestly haven't come up with anything workable in R and have just been attempting to manipulate data in excel prior to importing it.  Please let me know if there's more information you need from me in order to help out - long time reader, first time poster.

Thanks!

Comment: It will help if you provide some data. Example rows from each data frame, as plain text (not images), and some example output.

Comment: I'll edit the post to include some data - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to convert this data to "POSIXct" class objects, this is the way base R stores dates. From there, we can take time differences and find the rows that are within the acceptable time window. Finally, split the data by UNIT, calculate the median, and bind the data back into a data.frame that looks like the original data.

Creating example data

```
UNIT <- c("BLUE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE", "YELLOW")
TIME <- paste(rep(10:12, each = 3600), rep(0:59, each = 60), 0:59, sep = ":")
x <- data.frame(
    UNIT = UNIT,
    LONG = NA, LAT = NA,
    TIME = rep(TIME, each = length(UNIT))
)
x$LONG <- stats::rnorm(nrow(x), mean = -133.53, sd = 0.1)
x$LAT  <- stats::rnorm(nrow(x), mean =   57.31, sd = 0.1)


StartTime <- c("11:00:00", "11:51:25", "12:15:17")
```

Actual computations

```
# the "2000-01-01" is arbitrary, just used to convert our times to class "POSIXct" 
#     which can be used to calculate time differences
.StartTime <- as.POSIXct(paste0("2000-01-01 ", StartTime))
.TIME      <- as.POSIXct(paste0("2000-01-01 ", x$TIME))


# loop through each StartTime
median.dat <- lapply(.StartTime, function(.StartTimei) {
    
    
    # figure out which TIME values are within the 1 minute window
    within <- abs(.TIME - .StartTimei) <= .difftime(30, units = "secs")
    
    
    # select the rows corresponding to times within the acceptable range
    dat <- x[within, , drop = FALSE]
    
    
    # select columns "LONG" and "LAT", then split the rows by "UNIT"
    dat <- split(dat[c("LONG", "LAT")], dat$UNIT)
    
    
    # for each "UNIT", ...    
    dat <- lapply(X = dat, FUN = function(dati) {
        
        
        # find the median of "LONG" and "LAT"
        vapply(X = dati, FUN = "median", FUN.VALUE = NA_real_)
    })
    
    
    # bind this list of data into a matrix
    dat <- do.call("rbind", dat)
    
    
    # attach the "UNIT" and "TIME" so it looks like the original data.frame
    return(data.frame(
        UNIT = rownames(dat),
        dat,
        TIME = .StartTimei,
        row.names = NULL
    ))
})


# bind this list of data into a data.frame
median.dat <- do.call("rbind", median.dat)


print(median.dat)
```